# Are decentralised applications storing full underlying blockchain on my device?

Tags: decentralized-applications

Let's say I have few **dapp**s installed on my smartphone. Are they storing full blockchain they are using on my device, or where it's stored?

Answer (score 1):

No, your device doesn't hold the whole blockchain on it's storage (a blockchain is typically counted in GBs, while your app is probably a few MBs).

The key is **[IFPS](https://ipfs.io/)** (from [How do dApps store data ? on Hackernoon](https://hackernoon.com/how-do-dapps-store-data-2968d99547a1))

> Store only the content hashes on the blockchain. So, while the
>   blockchain stores only the hashes, the hashes themselves provide an
>   easy way to retrieve the large files being stored.

How it works (from [ipfs.io](https://ipfs.io/)):

- Each file and all of the blocks within it are given a unique fingerprint called a cryptographic hash.
- IPFS removes duplications across the network.
- Each network node stores only content it is interested in, and some indexing information that helps figure out who is storing what
- When looking up files, you're asking the network to find nodes
  storing the content behind a unique hash.
- Every file can be found by human-readable names using a decentralized naming system called IPNS.

I suggest you to read the whole Hackernoon article if you want to understand it deeper.

Comment: I personally feel that the linked article does not answer OP's question. OP is asking if the blockchain is stored on a device interacting with the blockchain network via a DApp. OP is not asking how the data or what format of the data is stored on-chain vs. off-chain.

Comment: This was just to give OP some pointer on how to dive further. Obviously the answer to me was "no" and the first paragraph would have been sufficient. But I do not agree with your statement "OP is asking if the blockchain is stored on a device interacting with the blockchain network via a DApp". To me, OP is clearly asking 'Are they storing full blockchain they are using on my device, or where it's stored?'. The answer is IFPS (and decentralization, broadly)

Answer (score 1):

It is **highly unlikely** that the entirety of a blockchain is being stored on your device, nor is it likely that the blockchain data needs to exist on your device especially if you are simply using a DApp. The only real necessity for having the entirety of a blockchain or even snapshots of a blockchain stored on your mobile device would be if you are running a full or light node directly on your mobile device.

DApps are simply a user interface for subsequent interaction with a blockchain network. The blockchain network data is "stored" on a series of nodes which the DApp is *interacting with* via APIs. Think of this in terms of the Stack Overflow application. Your machine does not store the entire database of Stack Overflow, it simply requests and updates data via a series of APIs.